# Sustraer valor columna de la misma columna, registro anterior

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Buenas tardes, tengo una tabla `Control_Kilometrajes` de la cual necesito sacar una nueva columna llamada `Recorrido`, y se saca a partir de la columna `Kilometraje`: al kilometraje mayor se le resta el menor, mientras `Placa_FK` sea la misma.

Desconozco del tema, así que se acepta cualquier sugerencia: ¿es posible hacerlo mediante una consulta sql?

Les dejo la tabla con los datos:

```
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Kilometrajes_PK | Placa_FK | Carga_Combustible_FK | Fecha      | Turno   | Kilometraje | Fecha_Captura    | Usuario_Entrada |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 79              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 14/08/2017 | Inicial | 179455      | 28/08/2017 19:33 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 78              | TYF9044  | 19                   | 14/08/2017 | Inicial | 179953      | 28/08/2017 19:32 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 80              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 28/08/2017 | Final   | 179954      | 28/08/2017 19:33 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 82              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 15/08/2017 | Final   | 180410      | 28/08/2017 19:39 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 83              | TYF9044  | 21                   | 16/08/2017 | Inicial | 180422      | 28/08/2017 19:40 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 84              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 16/08/2017 | Final   | 180757      | 28/08/2017 19:40 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 85              | TYF9044  | 22                   | 17/08/2017 | Inicial | 180769      | 28/08/2017 19:41 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 86              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 17/08/2017 | Final   | 180988      | 28/08/2017 19:42 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 87              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 18/08/2017 | Final   | 181345      | 28/08/2017 19:44 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 88              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 19/08/2017 | Inicial | 181357      | 28/08/2017 19:44 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 89              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 19/08/2017 | Final   | 181358      | 28/08/2017 19:45 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 90              | TYF9044  | 23                   | 21/08/2017 | Inicial | 181379      | 28/08/2017 19:45 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 91              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 21/08/2017 | Final   | 181677      | 28/08/2017 19:46 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 92              | TYF9044  | 24                   | 22/08/2017 | Inicial | 181678      | 28/08/2017 19:46 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 93              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 22/08/2017 | Final   | 182074      | 28/08/2017 19:47 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 94              | TYF9044  | 25                   | 23/08/2017 | Inicial | 182075      | 28/08/2017 19:48 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 95              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 23/08/2017 | Final   | 182455      | 28/08/2017 19:48 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 96              | TYF9044  | 26                   | 24/08/2017 | Inicial | 182456      | 28/08/2017 19:49 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 97              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 24/08/2017 | Final   | 182819      | 28/08/2017 19:49 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 98              | TYF9044  | 27                   | 25/08/2017 | Inicial | 182831      | 28/08/2017 19:50 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 99              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 25/08/2017 | Final   | 182880      | 28/08/2017 19:50 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 100             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 26/08/2017 | Inicial | 182894      | 28/08/2017 19:50 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 101             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 26/08/2017 | Final   | 182895      | 28/08/2017 19:51 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 102             | TYF9044  | 28                   | 28/08/2017 | Inicial | 182909      | 28/08/2017 19:53 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 105             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 29/08/2017 | Inicial | 183264      | 29/08/2017 12:40 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 111             | TYF9044  | 30                   | 30/08/2017 | Final   | 183299      | 30/08/2017 09:02 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 109             | TYF9044  | 29                   | 30/08/2017 | Inicial | 183313      | 30/08/2017 08:59 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 115             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 30/08/2017 | Final   | 183591      | 31/08/2017 14:59 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 129             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 30/09/2017 | Inicial | 183603      | 01/09/2017 09:48 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 131             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 31/08/2017 | Final   | 183604      | 01/09/2017 09:51 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 114             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 31/08/2017 | Inicial | 183608      | 31/08/2017 14:59 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 130             | TYF9044  | 33                   | 01/09/2017 | Inicial | 183622      | 01/09/2017 09:50 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 137             | TYF9044  | 34                   | 01/09/2017 | Final   | 183921      | 02/09/2017 11:51 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 147             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Final   | 183932      | 04/09/2017 08:58 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 136             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Inicial | 183937      | 02/09/2017 11:48 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 146             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 04/09/2017 | Inicial | 183978      | 04/09/2017 08:57 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 153             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 04/09/2017 | Final   | 183979      | 05/09/2017 08:46 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 152             | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 05/09/2017 | Inicial | 184000      | 05/09/2017 08:45 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 33              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 26/08/2017 | Inicial | 35146       | 26/08/2017 13:08 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 34              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 07/08/2017 | Inicial | 35147       | 26/08/2017 13:08 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 35              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 07/08/2017 | Inicial | 35191       | 26/08/2017 13:09 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 36              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 08/08/2017 | Inicial | 35200       | 26/08/2017 13:10 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 37              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 08/08/2017 | Final   | 35246       | 26/08/2017 13:10 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 38              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 09/08/2017 | Inicial | 35258       | 26/08/2017 13:11 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 39              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 09/08/2017 | Final   | 35313       | 26/08/2017 13:11 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 40              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 10/08/2017 | Inicial | 35324       | 26/08/2017 13:12 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 122             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 31/08/2017 | Inicial | 101780      | 31/08/2017 15:06 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 20              | TYJ1667  | 7                    | 16/08/2017 | Inicial | 174475      | 22/08/2017 19:54 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 17              | TYJ1667  | 5                    | 14/08/2017 | Inicial | 176753      | 22/08/2017 19:50 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 18              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 14/08/2017 | Final   | 177138      | 22/08/2017 19:51 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 64              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 14/08/2017 | Final   | 177139      | 26/08/2017 14:52 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 0               | TYJ1667  | 0                    | 15/08/2017 | Inicial | 177149      | 15/08/2017 17:37 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 19              | TYJ1667  | 6                    | 15/08/2017 | Final   | 177474      | 22/08/2017 19:53 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 21              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 16/08/2017 | Final   | 177813      | 22/08/2017 19:54 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 22              | TYJ1667  | 8                    | 17/08/2017 | Inicial | 177827      | 22/08/2017 19:55 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 23              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 10/08/2017 | Final   | 177919      | 22/08/2017 19:55 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 24              | TYJ1667  | 9                    | 17/08/2017 | Final   | 177920      | 22/08/2017 19:56 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 25              | TYJ1667  | 10                   | 18/08/2017 | Inicial | 177933      | 22/08/2017 19:57 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 26              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 18/08/2017 | Final   | 178204      | 22/08/2017 19:57 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 27              | TYJ1667  | 11                   | 19/08/2017 | Inicial | 178208      | 22/08/2017 19:58 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 28              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 19/08/2017 | Final   | 178276      | 22/08/2017 19:59 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 29              | TYJ1667  | 12                   | 21/08/2017 | Inicial | 178294      | 22/08/2017 19:59 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 30              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 21/08/2017 | Final   | 178586      | 22/08/2017 20:00 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 31              | TYJ1667  | 13                   | 22/08/2017 | Inicial | 178594      | 22/08/2017 20:00 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 32              | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 22/08/2017 | Final   | 178874      | 22/08/2017 20:01 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 107             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 30/08/2017 | Inicial | 179584      | 30/08/2017 08:56 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 120             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 30/08/2017 | Final   | 179611      | 31/08/2017 15:03 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 119             | TYJ1667  | 32                   | 31/08/2017 | Inicial | 179634      | 31/08/2017 15:03 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 125             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 30/09/2017 | Final   | 179654      | 01/09/2017 09:45 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 126             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 01/09/2017 | Inicial | 179668      | 01/09/2017 09:46 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 141             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 01/09/2017 | Final   | 179669      | 02/09/2017 11:56 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 140             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Inicial | 179820      | 02/09/2017 11:55 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 145             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Final   | 179889      | 04/09/2017 08:57 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 144             | TYJ1667  | 35                   | 04/09/2017 | Inicial | 179900      | 04/09/2017 08:56 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 154             | TYJ1667  | 37                   | 05/09/2017 | Inicial | 179953      | 05/09/2017 08:47 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 155             | TYJ1667  | NULL                 | 04/09/2017 | Final   | 179954      | 05/09/2017 08:48 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 128             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 01/09/2017 | Inicial | 38266       | 01/09/2017 09:47 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 138             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Inicial | 38381       | 02/09/2017 11:51 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 139             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 01/09/2017 | Final   | 38382       | 02/09/2017 11:54 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 149             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Final   | 38408       | 04/09/2017 09:00 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 148             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 04/09/2017 | Inicial | 38415       | 04/09/2017 08:59 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 158             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 05/09/2017 | Inicial | 38621       | 05/09/2017 08:49 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 159             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 04/09/2017 | Final   | 38622       | 05/09/2017 08:50 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 167             | Z56NP    | NULL                 | 02/09/2017 | Final   | 46274       | 05/09/2017 09:23 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 81              | Z56NP    | 20                   | 15/08/2017 | Inicial | 179966      | 28/08/2017 19:38 | TCAMANSUP       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

El resultado esperado sería como esto:

```
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Kilometrajes_PK | Placa_FK | Carga_Combustible_FK | Fecha      | Turno   | Kilometraje | Fecha_Captura    | Usuario_Entrada | Recorrido |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 103             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 14/08/2017 | Final   | 101208      | 28/08/2017 19:55 | TCAMANSUP       |           |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 104             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 17/08/2017 | Inicial | 101217      | 28/08/2017 19:56 | TCAMANSUP       | 9         |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 135             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 31/08/2017 | Inicial | 101779      | 01/09/2017 10:12 | TCAMANSUP       | 562       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 121             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 30/08/2017 | Final   | 101780      | 31/08/2017 15:05 | TCAMANSUP       | 1         |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 134             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 01/09/2017 | Inicial | 101781      | 01/09/2017 10:11 | TCAMANSUP       | 1         |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 161             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 04/09/2017 | Inicial | 101783      | 05/09/2017 08:55 | TCAMANSUP       | 2         |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 160             | LXN6434  | NULL                 | 05/09/2017 | Inicial | 101786      | 05/09/2017 08:54 | TCAMANSUP       | 3         |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 79              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 14/08/2017 | Inicial | 179455      | 28/08/2017 19:33 | TCAMANSUP       |           |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 78              | TYF9044  | 19                   | 14/08/2017 | Inicial | 179953      | 28/08/2017 19:32 | TCAMANSUP       | 498       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 80              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 28/08/2017 | Final   | 179954      | 28/08/2017 19:33 | TCAMANSUP       | 1         |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 82              | TYF9044  | NULL                 | 15/08/2017 | Final   | 180410      | 28/08/2017 19:39 | TCAMANSUP       | 456       |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 83              | TYF9044  | 21                   | 16/08/2017 | Inicial | 180422      | 28/08/2017 19:40 | TCAMANSUP       | 12        |
+-----------------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: ¿Quieres agregar una columnas llamada `Recorrido` a tu tabla `Control_Kilometrajes` o quieres una consulta que contenga una columna adicional llamada `Recorrido`?. Podrías editar tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola Davlio, gracias por tu comentario, ya modifiqué la pregunta. Me gustaría una nueva columna con el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta puede ser una solución, sin duda hay más sencillas pero ahora no se me ocurren. La idea es trabajar con dos subconsultas dónde generamos un número de orden por cada placa a partir de [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) y luego simplemente hacemos `JOIN` entre una fila y la siguiente.

```
    SELECT  K1.Placa_FK,
        K1.Kilometraje,
        K1.Kilometrajes_PK,
        K1.Placa_FK,
        K1.Carga_Combustible_FK,
        K1.Fecha,
        K1.Turno,
        K1.Kilometraje,
        Fecha_Captura,
        Usuario_Entrada,
        CASE WHEN K2.Kilometraje IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE K1.Kilometraje - isnull(K2.Kilometraje,0) END as Recorrido
        FROM (SELECT  Placa_FK,
                      Kilometraje,
                      Kilometrajes_PK,
                      Placa_FK,
                      Carga_Combustible_FK,
                      Fecha,
                      Turno,
                      Kilometraje,
                      Fecha_Captura,
                      Usuario_Entrada
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Placa_FK ORDER BY Kilometraje ASC) as Nro
                      FROM Control_Kilometrajes K1
              ) K1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT  Placa_FK,
                           Kilometraje,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Placa_FK ORDER BY Kilometraje ASC) as Nro
                           FROM Control_Kilometrajes
                   ) K2
                   ON K1.Placa_FK = K2.Placa_FK
                   and K1.Nro = K2.Nro + 1 
        ORDER BY K1.Placa_FK, K1.Kilometraje ASC
```

Editado: Esta otra forma creo que es mejor y algo más sencilla:

```
SELECT  K1.Placa_FK,
        K1.Kilometraje,
        K1.Kilometrajes_PK,
        K1.Placa_FK,
        K1.Carga_Combustible_FK,
        K1.Fecha,
        K1.Turno,
        K1.Kilometraje,
        K1.Fecha_Captura,
        K1.Usuario_Entrada,
        K1.Kilometraje - MAX(K2.Kilometraje)  AS Recorrido
        FROM Control_Kilometrajes K1
        LEFT JOIN Control_Kilometrajes K2
           ON K1.Placa_FK = K2.Placa_FK
           AND K2.Kilometraje < K1.Kilometraje
        GROUP BY
           K1.Placa_FK,
           K1.Kilometraje
           K1.Kilometrajes_PK,
           K1.Placa_FK,
           K1.Carga_Combustible_FK,
           K1.Fecha,
           K1.Turno,
           K1.Kilometraje,
           K1.Fecha_Captura,
           K1.Usuario_Entrada
        ORDER BY K1.Placa_FK, K1.Kilometraje ASC
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio!, funciona a la perfección!!! Ahora me toca averiguar cómo meter aquí el join que le hacía con Cargas_Combustibles. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

esta es la forma como yo lo hice 
se trata de numerar la misma consulta dos veces y luego  juntar el renglon 1 con el 2 y hacer la resta de km

```
declare @tabla table (
  vehiculo    varchar(10),
  fecha       datetime,
  KmAlSurtir  int,
  GasSurtida  float
)  






select t2.renglon, t2.fecha, t2.kmAlSurtir  , t2.kmAlSurtir -t1.kmAlSurtir as kmsRecorridos  
from      (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vehiculo ORDER BY fecha ) AS Renglon ,* from @tabla) as t2
left join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vehiculo ORDER BY fecha ) AS Renglon ,* from @tabla) as t1 on t2.vehiculo=t1.vehiculo and t2.renglon=t1.renglon+1
```